# Converting Vb.Net Linq to C# but Distinct Error

Tags: c#, vb.net, linq, compiler-errors, distinct

I am trying to move some of my code over from vb.net to c# class library. I have linq query in vb.net that is querying against a DataTable.

```
Dim qryUser = From db In dt.AsEnumerable() _
              Select userName = db.Field(Of String)("UserName") Distinct
              Order By userName Ascending
```

Now I am trying to make this work in C# and I have

```
IEnumerable<string> qryUser = (from db in Table.AsEnumerable()
                               orderby db.Field<string>("UserName") ascending
                               select db.Field<string>("UserName"));
```

Now all examples I have found searching, shows I should just have to add

```
.Distinct()
```

to the end of my c# linq query to make it look like this

```
IEnumerable<string> qryUser = (from db in Table.AsEnumerable()
                               orderby db.Field<string>("UserName") ascending
                               select db.Field<string>("UserName")).Distinct()
```

but doing this gives me an error in my IDE

> Error 1   'System.Data.EnumerableRowCollection' does not contain
>   a definition for 'Distinct' and no extension method 'Distinct'
>   accepting a first argument of type
>   'System.Data.EnumerableRowCollection' could be found

Can someone, please, show me the proper way of doing this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you add the `userName =` part in the C# code that you have omitted from the VB?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to copy/paste your code (and setup a small `DataTable`) and it worked fine.

The `Distinct` extension method lives in the `System.Linq` namespace.

Make sure the following `using` directive is at the top of your class file:

```
using System.Linq;
```

Comment: Holy fail on my part. I completely forgot the using System.Linq